# Restyling a website into Ember

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, attributes, view

I have been handed tasked with rewriting a website into an Ember app.
So far so good, I understand the basics of Ember routing, models, controllers etc. I am getting hung on details now though.
Right now I am having trouble with how to implement Ember views and attribute binding.
I have an element like this:

```
<a class="someClass" href="http://example.com" data-imgone="public/images/firstimg.jpg" data-imgtwo="public/images/secondimg.jpg" data-title="someTitle" data-description="someDescription">
    <div>
        <!-- some stuff -->
    </div>
</a>
```

As I have understood it (most likely wrong though lol) I should create this element as a view in my script:

```
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'a',
    attributeBindings: ['href', 'data-imgone', 'data-imgtwo', 'data-title', 'data-description'],
    href: 'http://example.com',
    'data-imgone': "public/images/firstimg.jpg",
    'data-imgtwo': "public/images/secondimg.jpg",
    data-title="someTitle",
    data-description="someDescription"
});
```

Then I should call myView with the view helper:

```
{{#view 'App.MyView}}
    <div>
        <!-- some stuff -->
    </div>
{{/view}}
```

This doesn't work, the elements are not being rendered. Please tell me what I am doing wrong. Have I completely misunderstood the point of views and attribute binding?
Also please if anyone has any tips/strategies for assignments such as mine please share them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a single quote to specify which view you're rendering. This should be enough:

```
{{#view App.SomeView}}Link Text{{/view}}
```

You also don't need quotes for declaring the data attributes in your class. The data attributes can be mapped like this:

```
App.SomeView = Em.View.extend({

  tagName: 'a', 
  attributeBindings: ['href', 'dataImgone:data-imgone'],

  href: 'http://emberjs.com',
  dataImgone: "public/images/firstimg.jpg",
});
```

(see [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yeyujozapoqo/2/edit))

Note that in the `attributeBindings`, I'm passing the function/property that feeds an attribute followed by `:attributename` which in this case is `data-imgone`, as `['dataImgone:data-imgone']`.

Comment: Just one last comment, try to use components instead of views whenever possible

Comment: So if I understand http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/whats-the-difference-between-ember-helpers-components-and-views/2201 right: views are never necessary anymore?

Comment: Not really. I still see some use cases where you're better off working with a view. rare cases tho. for what you seem to be doing, i'd use a component.